# how to return multiple values from switch case in java method?

Tags: java

```
            case 't':
            case 'u':
            case 'v':
                number = "8";
                break;

            case 'w':

                number = "9";
                break;

    return number;
```

I want my output to be "889" when my input is "uvw". and then i want to return 899 to the main method. Please help!!!

Comment: A `switch` statement is the wrong structure for this problem.  You can try using a map of letters to values.

Comment: Please post the whole method. Are there any other cases?

Comment: If you want output to be `889`, why would you want return value to be `899` *(different middle digit)*?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `switch` is a workable choice for mapping letters to phone-pad digits. A `Map` isn't any better, since you still need to define all 26 mappings, and it requires boxing the characters.

Comment: @Andreas Yes I guess he could iterate over each digit and use a `switch`, I hadn't thought of it the way you just did.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume your input is a String. You can accomplish what you want by using a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
public static void makeString(String input) {
    // We will be building our output with the variable outputBuilder.
    StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // We want to iterate over all of the characters in the string and act accordingly.
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);

        // Now we switch and react to the specific character.
        switch(c) {
            case 't':
            case 'u':
            case 'v':
                outputBuilder.append('8');
                break;
            case 'w':
                outputBuilder.append('9');
                break;
            default:
                // what happens with other characters? Anything?
        }
    }

    // Now we have iterated over all the characters.
    // We can build the output now and return it!
    return outputBuilder.toString();
}
```

Now, if you want to use this in your `main(String[])` method, simply invoke it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sampleInput = "uvw";
    System.out.println("Calling the method on the sample input gives us: " +
        makeString(sampleInput)
    );
}
```

When executed, this sample program will print the following message:

> Calling the method on the sample input gives us: 889

Comment: Please call 1-555-GoodAnswer (1-555-466-3267 ext. 937) for your winning price.